# Automatically move physical network interfaces to namespace

Tags: networking, systemd, udev

I would like all of the physical interfaces on my system to live within a specific network namespace called "physical". It's easy enough to move devices over manually using commands like `ip link set enp2s0 netns physical` and `iw phy phy0 set netns name physical`, but I would like this to happen automatically both at boot and for any devices connected at runtime.

It seems like the best way to accomplish this would be via udev rules, or possibly some systemd magic.

My first thought was just to write a udev rule that runs the appropriate command, but I ran into a couple of questions I haven't been able to answer via my searches:

1. How do I distinguish physical interfaces from virtual interfaces?
2. How do I tell WLAN interfaces apart so I can issue the `iw` command instead of the `ip` command?
3. How do I get the name of a WLAN phy so I can pass it to the `iw` command?

I was hoping the above would be relatively straightforward, but I don't see any obvious distinguishing factors in `udevadm info`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these informations are retrievable from `/sys`:

1a. `/sys/class/net/` : list of network devices, all types included

1b. `/sys/devices/virtual/net/` : list of virtual network devices: includes `lo`, tunnels, veth, bridges ... so if it's in the former but not this one, it should be physical.

23. if a device is a modern wireless device (driver), it will have the entry `/sys/class/net/<device>/phy82011/name`, eg:

    ```
    $ grep -s --with-filename ''  /sys/class/net/*/phy80211/name
    /sys/class/net/wlan0/phy80211/name:phy0
    /sys/class/net/wlan1/phy80211/name:phy1
    /sys/class/net/wlan2/phy80211/name:phy2
    ```

So by running the adequate script from `udev` environment and comparing with those directories and files from `/sys`, you should have all the needed informations to do it.

Just as a side note, if later, to work on those devices, you change only the *network* namespace (*eg* using `nsenter --net=/var/run/netns/physical`), `/sys` will still be in the host's *mount* namespace, and won't reflect the arrival of those devices but will instead show them missing. Using `ip netns exec physical command` is fine, it does change mount namespace and remounts `/sys` for you.

Comment: In other words, have udev call an external script for all new net devices, and make it the script's responsibility to determine whether/how to move the interface? I suppose if udev doesn't expose the needed attributes itself, that's probably my best bet. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Based on A.B's answer, I came up with the following rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DEVPATH!="/devices/virtual/*", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="physical-namespace@.service"
```

`DEVPATH!="/devices/virtual/*` is the key to only grabbing physical devices. `physical-namespace@.service` is a oneshot service that moves the interface to the desired namespace (`physical`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Move interface to physical namespace
Requires=netns@physical.service
After=netns@physical.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/move-netif %I physical
```

(`netns@.service` just creates a network namespace of the given name.)

Finally, `move-netif` is responsible for figuring out how to move the interface:

```
#!/bin/bash

devpath="$1"
target_ns="$2"

if [[ -e "$devpath/phy80211" ]]; then
  phy="$(basename "$(readlink "$devpath/phy80211")")"
  iw phy "$phy" set netns name "$target_ns"
else
  ifname="$(basename "$devpath")"
  ip link set "$ifname" netns "$target_ns"
fi
```

Comment: Have you found a way to automatically stop the systemd service when the device is removed? I tried with `BindsTo` and with adding a udev remove event handler, but the problem is the system sees the device as being removed at the time it changes netns, which is way too early...